# Jsoup dynamic post link doesn't follow the redirect

Tags: javascript, java, post, jsoup, redirect

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head></head>
 <body onload="document.formSaml.submit()">
  <form name="formSaml" method="post" action="https://sisterif.agenziaentrate.gov.it" target="_self">
   <input name="SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value="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">
  </form>   
  <title>

</title>  
  <form method="post" action="./apriServizio.aspx?idServizio=1&amp;guid=06279fda-22c6-4fa6-be60-c4d9b070c450" id="form1"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="rCQygBH80/0CL7UIQvXcddBT0+MTSJmlCoC0PM19/g+76kdnZzY3BMG+xu03d8yVOrg2EhKORR3dhGugT+d43Cy4nPRrgNx/wrSc/AEmRmQ="> 
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="FDDE2372"> 
   <div> 
   </div> 
  </form>   
 </body>
</html>
```

I try submit this form with this code:

```
Elements SAMLResponse = doc.select("input[name=SAMLResponse]");
                String SAMLResponseValue = SAMLResponse.attr("value");
document = Jsoup.connect("https://sisterif.agenziaentrate.gov.it")
                          .data("SAMLResponse", SAMLResponseValue)
                          .timeout(20000)
                          .followRedirects(true)
                          .post();



                System.out.println(document);
```

But the content of my document is:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head></head>
 <body onload="document.formSaml.submit()">
  <form name="formSaml" method="post" action="https://sisterif.agenziaentrate.gov.it" target="_self">
   <input name="SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value="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">
  </form>   
  <title>

</title>  
  <form method="post" action="./apriServizio.aspx?idServizio=1&amp;guid=06279fda-22c6-4fa6-be60-c4d9b070c450" id="form1"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="rCQygBH80/0CL7UIQvXcddBT0+MTSJmlCoC0PM19/g+76kdnZzY3BMG+xu03d8yVOrg2EhKORR3dhGugT+d43Cy4nPRrgNx/wrSc/AEmRmQ="> 
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="FDDE2372"> 
   <div> 
   </div> 
  </form>   
 </body>
</html>
```

jsoup does not follow the link in the body "onload =" document.formSaml.submit () "".
I've read at least 10 articles here on stackoverflow but did not find the solution to my problem.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think Jsoup can execute javascript.

Comment: If 10 articles on stackoverflow say: jsoup has no javascript engine, then maybe it is time to select an other tool for your dynamic problem... So have a look at htmlunit or selenium.

Comment: Jsoup version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the default user-agent

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("..url..").followRedirects(true);
con.request().removeHeader("User-Agent");
```